# Strawberry Perl/Eclipse/EPIC - Can't locate MySql.pm in @INC (you may need to install the MySql module)

Tags: mysql, eclipse, perl, strawberry-perl

I'm using Eclipse with Strawberry Perl and Eclipse EPIC plugin.

I'm new to perl and am trying to connect to a mysql db I have setup. When I try to use the `use MySql;` I get an error that:

> Can't locate MySql.pm in @INC (you may need to install the MySql
>   module) (@INC contains:  C:/strawberry/perl/site/lib
>   C:/strawberry/perl/vendor/lib C:/strawberry/perl/lib  .)

I'm trying to do a simple tutorial for a query from: http://www.tizag.com/perlT/perlmysqlquery.php

Doing some googling, it looks like strawberry perl is suppose to have the DBD::mysql already installed.

I'm currently at a loss, perhaps I need to update my path, or eclipse environment or perhaps there is a different use I need to use?

Some details of my setup:

- Windows 8 OS
- Strawberry perl v5.18.2
- Eclipse Kepler Service Release 2

Comment: Don't use that tutorial, not only has `MySql.pm` been deprecated for years, the code examples don't even `use strict; use warnings;`! Yuck. Take a look at the documentation for [`DBI`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI) instead. A good tutorial on modern Perl practices wouldn't hurt either.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, thanks for the info, it was a big help. The link you gave provided me with a bunch of insight. I found a simple example on cpan as well that I was able to get working with DBI ( http://search.cpan.org/~capttofu/DBD-mysql-4.028/lib/DBD/mysql.pm ) thanks!

Comment: Good to hear. I wrote an answer for any other poor saps who may stumble on that tutorial in the future. Fortunately, `Mysql.pm` is unlikely to be on any current systems, so even if someone does try to use the code from the tutorial, it won't compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yikes! That tutorial is crap. Perhaps at one time it was cutting-edge Perl, but it is way out of date. The module `Mysql.pm` was deprecated way back in 2006! You should be using [`DBI`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI) instead.

Also, you should include the statements `use strict;` and `use warnings;` at the top of *every* Perl script you ever write. If you find a tutorial that doesn't include those directives in example scripts, stop reading and look for a new tutorial immediately.<sup>*</sup>

The following shows how to connect to a MySQL database using the `DBI` module and print out the results of a `SELECT` statement. See the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI) for details.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use DBI;

my $dsn = "DBI:mysql:test;localhost";
my $user = 'user';
my $pass = 'pass';

my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $pass, {
    PrintError => 0,
    RaiseError => 1
});

my $statement = <<'SQL';
    SELECT foo
    FROM bar
SQL

my $sth = $dbh->prepare($statement);
$sth->execute;

while (my $row = $sth->fetch) {
    say "@$row";
}

$dbh->disconnect;
```

---

* Short code snippets don't need these but if an example script includes a shebang line (e.g. `#!/usr/bin/perl`), it had better have `strict` and `warnings`, too.

Answer (score 0):

This is a summary based on ThisSuitIsBlackNot's suggest to me. His suggestions was correct, the example I was doing was not using DBD, but instead deprecated code. Reading the link he provided gave me insight into the cpan and a couple more googles gave me an example from cpan that let me connect to my MySQL db without any issues. Here is a link to the example in case anyone else runs into similar issues: http://search.cpan.org/~capttofu/DBD-mysql-4.028/lib/DBD/mysql.pm